# Products not appearing in manage > products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

To sum things up, when I go to Manage > Categories in "All store views" I can see the products in "Category products". When I switch to another store view, no product is showing.

And in Manage > products I can't see these products even if I'm on "All store views"

I checked the stock, many products are in stock.
How can I assign all the category products to a specific store view? 
PS. I have a multi-store website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you do not have any filters setup, in the product grid. Turn off all installed extensions, compiler, and reindex everything.

If this douse not help, try exporting all the products in this particular store. And make a export in a store that works fine, or a fresh install and compare the two files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't open any product. They don't show on the manage -> products grid.
I can only see them on the category page

Comment: Oke, check if you do not have any filters setup, in the product grid. Turn off all installed extensions, compiler, and reindex everything. 

If this douse not help, try exporting all the products in this particular store. And make a export in a store that works fine, or a fresh install and compare the two files.

Comment: Thanks @baconl, that works fine.
Can you write your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it?